# About to print KERNEL messages on terminal

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

According to manual page it told that if priority of message's log level is higher than default set log level then it will be printed on terminal. But when I had used sentence like

```
printk(KERN_ALERT " MESSAGE ")
```

I am facing problem to print message on terminal. Because the default priority is set to 4 and `KERN_ALERT` has priority `1`, which is higher.

So, how can I print message on terminal?

Comment: Before answering, can I ask why you want this? If you want this for debugging, _don't do it_. This is only for extremely bad situations where you'd want to print something to screen. Basically only when the computer is about to explode. So why do you need this?

Comment: I am doing programming in driver. so every time i have to do dmesg or check syslog file. If it'll print message on terminal then it'll we faster for me to do debugging by printk.

Answer (score 4):

It should print messages to the *console*, not to the *terminal*. Sometimes the console and the terminal seems the same, but it is not. Edit */proc/sys/kernel/printk* to set up the lowest priority to print in console

Comment: Thanks for giving answer, but this file is readable file. it doesn't have permission to write

Comment: Are you root when you try to write to it?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 22 apr 11.43 /proc/sys/kernel/printk`.

Usually, you must be root to edit this file

Answer (score 3):

I know that this doesn't exactly answer your question, but like I said in the comments, making `printk` log to the console is generally not a good idea. This is an alternative I suggest that should well enough serve your purpose.

Since you want to use it for debug purposes, you could simply open a new terminal and execute the following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

or

```
tail -f /var/log/dmesg
```

or the like. `tail -f` would print the last messages in the file, but would keep waiting for updates. As soon as there are more lines written in the file, `tail -f` would write them to console for you.

Regardless of whether you use this method or directly print to console, you may also be interested in defining a macro that calls `printk` and in debug mode would also put a small `msleep` after to make sure the log makes it to the screen, in case of crashes. This is done like this:

```
set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
msleep(/* amount in milliseconds */);
```

Comment: Thanks shahbaz.


Apart from thinking that "printk log to the console is generally not a good idea", shall i say that it is impossible to print kernel messages on console ??

Comment: I don't think it is _impossible_. It may be very hard though, not to mention it may often not make sense anyway, because you don't necessarily load the modules through a terminal. During start-up, it's quite easy to have something printed in the console as you can see in the start-up messages.

Comment: The man page of `printk` says: _We try to grab the console_sem. If we succeed, it's easy - we log the output and call the console drivers. If we fail to get the semaphore we place the output into the log buffer and return._ so you may want to look also into why `printk` may fail in taking the `console_sem`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem initially developing skeleton drivers on host system. every time I had to check with "dmesg" command.

I have to edit /proc/sys/kernel/printk .

For getting message on Terminal with window manager such ad KED and Gnome 
run "tail -f /var/log/kern.log &" to get messages on terminal.

It helped me in Ubuntu system. Hope it will help :)